# One-Click OpenLiteSpeed WordPress Server :: www and no-www URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, litespeed

I'm totally new to OpenLiteSpeed.
Used "One-Click OpenLiteSpeed WordPress Server" to create a new server with a wordpress page.
I need to keep the www on the URLs if the user use www
And keep no-www if user dont use this.
Current vehabiour is ALL redirected to NO-WWW

The OpenLiteSpeed generated .htaccess is very big and I dont know how to change this

```
### Forcing HTTPS rule start       
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
### Forcing HTTPS rule end

# BEGIN LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine on
CacheLookup on
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:no-autoflush]

### marker CACHE RESOURCE start ###
RewriteRule wp-content/.*/[^/]*(responsive|css|js|dynamic|loader|fonts)\.php - [E=cache-control:max-age=3600]
### marker CACHE RESOURCE end ###

### marker LOGIN COOKIE start ###
RewriteRule .? - [E="Cache-Vary:wp-postpass_053d2cb8322713aa27e9498545fa1ddb"]
### marker LOGIN COOKIE end ###

### marker FAVICON start ###
RewriteRule favicon\.ico$ - [E=cache-control:max-age=86400]
### marker FAVICON end ###

### marker DROPQS start ###
CacheKeyModify -qs:fbclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:gclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:utm*
CacheKeyModify -qs:_ga
### marker DROPQS end ###

</IfModule>
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END NON_LSCACHE
# BEGIN WordPress
# Las directivas (líneas) entre `BEGIN WordPress` y `END WordPress` se generan dinámicamente, y solo se deberían modificar mediante filtros de WordPress.
# Cualquier cambio en las directivas que hay entre esos marcadores se sobrescribirá.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: what is your WP home URL and site URL ?   if I recall correctly , WP will also redirect it if hostname doesn't match.      e.g.  if you set url to www.domain.com  , then when you access it by domain.com  , even without htaccess, WP will also redirect to www.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

Finally I convinced the client to keep the current behaviour.
Is not a good idea for SEO to habe www and no-www at the same time (an I'm not sure if this is technically possible)

Answer (score -1):

This is mostly likely a wordpress setting issue rather than a Litespeed issue. Wordpress likes to take over urls. Under the settings section in the web admin panel select general:

WordPress Address (URL): 
Site Address (URL):

there you will most likely see the url is: 
site.com change that www.site.com
obviously put the (https) the post won't let me type it in haha.

and that will force the clients to load the site and and wordpress will "redirect" them to the url put there.